# EF Core Include() produces left join for required relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core

Why does the following LINQ query produce a `left join` rather than an `inner join` (using EF Core 7):

```
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children)
```

The relationship is configured as `IsRequired()`. Correspondingly `Children.ParentId` is not nullable in the database.

I'm finding contradicting statements on the internet. Some say that the above will always produce `left join`. Others say `inner join` if the relationship is required, and `left join` if not. Cannot find any clear documentation on this.

The database I'm using is Postgres.

Comment: Consder the case of a parent with 0 child rows. Should they be included in your query results or not? An `INNER JOIN` restricts the rows returned from both tables, whereas `LEFT OUTER JOIN` only restricts the right-side table, not the left-side table.

Comment: @Dai thanks for your reply, I know how `left` and `inner` joins work. I'm trying to understand how EF works - how it decides which join to use in the scenario I provided in the question.

Comment: "_how it decides which join to use in the scenario I provided in the question_" - EF knows that a `Parent` entity _might not_ have any `Children` entities (this is inherent in any 1-m relationship in an RDBMS); so when you do `Parents.Include ( p => p.Children )` it knows you want all Parents (even if they don't have any Children) hence why it uses `LEFT JOIN`. If you did `Children.Include( c => c.Parent )` then it would use an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is how SingleQuery Eager loading works. It produces LEFT JOIN for every included collection navigation property. INNER JOIN may filter out `Parents` when there are no children.

More to read: [Single vs. Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)